# Edge + Express + SQL Server unexplainable StackOverflow

Tags: c#, sql-server, node.js, express, edge.js

So I've been banging my head against a wall trying to figure this one out.  A StackOverflow is crashing my server whenever I try to retrieve data from SQL Server using several different methods but I am unable to pinpoint the exact cause of the issue.

I've been able to put together a structure with Express that retrieves data from my database when the server stands up, but when I attach a route to the same method, I get "the" StackOverflow (I'm unsure if there is a single cause for the crash or if I'm dealing with two separate issues that both manifest as Stack Overflows)

I'll focus this question on one of the stack overflows in the hope that it is responsible for all of the crashes.

At any rate, this is the server config that was able to marshal data back to node from the .NET class library(which in turn makes the ADO.NET calls into my MSSQL db):

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var edge = require('edge');

var app = express();
app.set('port',process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.use(app.router);


var repository = {
   list: edge.func({assemblyFile:'bin\\Data.dll',typeName:'Data.GetListTask',methodName:'Invoke'})
});


app.get('/tickets', repository.list);


http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'),function(request,response){
   console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
   console.log('[Before][repository.list]');
   repository.list({}, function(error, result) {
       console.log('[Result][repository.list]');
       if(result){
          result.forEach(function(item){
              console.log('[List contains]{' + item.Id + '|' + item.Description + '}');
          });
       }
       else{
         console.log('No items found');
       }
   });
});
```

Whenever the server starts, the repository's list is retrieved and spooled to the console; however, if I use my /tickets route, the server crashes with a Stack Overflow.

The "good" response:
[image: An image of the console as data is being marshaled back to node]

The crash when I try to activate my route (the real route is named 'tickets')
[image: An image of the crash when I try to activate my route]

I'm not very experienced with node or express, so I'm not entirely sure I've specified that '/tickets' route properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a stupid problem with my Express route.

```
app.get('/tickets', function (request, response) {
    ticketRepository.getTickets({}, function (error, result){
        response.json(result);
    });
});
```

returns the results from my database as expected.

**protip**: If you're trying to respond with "stuff", it helps to actually put "stuff" on the response.